# Explode in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, explode

I want to make a function that would explode a string into a list of string depending of the given character but for unknown reason the OCaml interpretor tells me that there's a syntax error on my 3rd line, character 6-7 which actually is the tabulation of my filter. I'm pretty confused. What did I do wrong?

```
let explode s c = 
    let rec explodeIn s c p l = function
        | p + 1 -> (String.sub s 0 p)::l
        | _     -> let idx = String.rindex_from s p c in; explodeIn s c (idx - 1) ((String.sub s (idx + 1) (p - idx))::l) (String.index s c)
    in
    explodeIn s c (String.lentgh - 1) [] (String.index s c)
;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p + 1` is not a valid pattern.

Maybe you meant `i when i = p + 1`

Edit:
There is also a couple of errors:
Invalid `;` after `in` (line 4)
Typo `String.lentgh` => `String.length s` (line 6)

Comment: Do works better  with a "when" thanks! Also yeah I noticed those typo and corrected them